# Unable to start gerrit.sh and thus unable to use gitweb

Tags: gerrit, gitweb

I am unable to start the gerrit.sh script. while running this script, it says starting failed. Below is the error that i can see in the error_log:

```
[2018-09-10 02:05:13,886] ERROR com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon : Unable to start daemon
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot bind to NewVoE-GIT01:29418
        at com.google.gerrit.sshd.SshDaemon.start(SshDaemon.java:290)
        at com.google.gerrit.lifecycle.LifecycleManager.start(LifecycleManager.java:74)
        at com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon.start(Daemon.java:258)
        at com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon.run(Daemon.java:186)
        at com.google.gerrit.pgm.util.AbstractProgram.main(AbstractProgram.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.invokeProgram(GerritLauncher.java:169)
        at com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.mainImpl(GerritLauncher.java:93)
        at com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.main(GerritLauncher.java:50)
        at Main.main(Main.java:25)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
```

Although my gerrit code review site is working fine but the gitweb option is not able to fetch the details from backend. Please suggest.

And thanks in advance for your help:)

Answer (score 1):

The error message:

> Address already in use

tells that there is already a service bound to port `29418` This prevents Gerrit's SSH daemon from starting up because it uses port `29418` by default.

You should check what is using that port, and stop it if possible, or configure Gerrit to listen to SSH on a different port. You can do the latter by setting [`sshd.listenAddress`](http://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.14/config-gerrit.html#sshd.listenAddress) in the site's `etc/gerrit.config` file.

Comment: I tried to change the SSH port to 29418 but its still not working. Its giving error as cannot bind to HTTP Port. Is there any other process needed to configure the port as SSH?